# Will an SQLite app run on an unrooted mobile phone?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am a budding android app programmer of 4 weeks and am surprised with it's complexity.
I am attempting to write a basic (Ahem) app which will chart 2 sets of integers over time in months.  I plan to use  an SQLite database and two activities. Marshmellow Android version.
My question is  will my app work on a mobile which hasn't root access.
I understand it will run OK on the Android studio emulator .
The database will be local internal only.
I have seached thoroughly for this answer but am left confused as the answers suggest that the directory where the data should be installed  ie) ....data/data  will not be reachable unless root access is obtained. However I see commonly available apps which must use permanent storage with SQLite such as Todo apps and personal note taking apps.
Maybe the permission is obtained programatically???
 I feel embarrest to ask such a simple question and will be obliged if anyone will help.

## Put more briefly- Will an SQLite app run on an unrooted mobile phone?

My reply to is this question "off Topic"?
This is not a debugging question at all as the code I am writing is working fine. The code ,  for me as a Android novice of 4 weeks duration , will be extensive once completed and there is a lot of work ahead of me .
The app wil use an SQLite database , a content provider,  a content resolver,  dialog and list fragments, an AsyncTaskLoader and in all 13 classes. All of these concepts are new to me. The point here being that I did not wish to invest so much time on this app on my journey to enlightenment of the Android system if I had missed or misunderstood a basic principle of the Android operating system.
Reseach? That was why I became confused, I rarely ask questions as I prefer to self learn  however I picked up somewhere that not all memory was available to unrooted phones and as I could not find a detailed memory model diagram I was  led to venture a direct question on stack overflow.
I am more familiar with the  Windows desktop applications memory model and C++ .
I am also familiar with the 8086 memory model through assembly language programming. It was  the hidden Android file system that hindered my understanding.
Was the restriction  part of a programming issue or was it an Android policy issue?(Now I know -Yes a  design policy)
I see no reason at all  to provide code samples because coding is not the direct  issue here and my intention was to be clear concise and direct with the question even if it risked appearing  to be naive. 
...."Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."....
I  politely point out that my question was fully understood by  several respected members of our community and in one case applauded for its simplicity and clarity.
Moreover clear helpful answers were given and in particular one excellent detailed answer was offered which must help many other novices to understand the concept.
This is a great forum and I do understand the need to uphold it's credibility and technical standards further more I do hope that I will be able to contribute more as the months pass.

Comment: The Android Framework supports SQLite https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Did you try to use a device? The answer is yes, it'll work root or not without permission. You only need permissions to read storage external to the application directory

Comment: Half of the apps in the market wouldn't run, without a database under the hoods. Just think to WhatsApp: does it require you to root your device?

Comment: You only need permissions to read storage external to the application directory – cricket_007.... Yes that is the info I was seeking thank you. it's easy when you know and we all have to start somewhere. Finding out was worth the markdown.

Comment: I think this is a valid and clear question, that shows research effort. I feel like people downvoted it just because they understand more than OP. Which doesn't make sense, because the purpose of this site is for people to ask about what they don't yet understand and for people who do to answer. Good question @Educ84free ! Don't get discouraged, keep learning and asking questions!

Answer (score 2):

In short: yes, your app will work!

SQLite database is something Android provides for app developers, regardless of wether the phone is rooted or not. Your research is correct as to where the operating system keeps the database. You might have across a term "internal storage" as well. On non-rooted phones it is a safe storage space, where each application can store data (SQLite DBs, text files, images, whatever it wants), but has access to only it's own data. Gmail most probably keeps some data there, but your application cannot access it. Similarly Gmail couldn't reach out of it's folder and access your application's data. You also can't look into those folders using any file explorer, either on the phone or by connecting the phone to a computer. Rooting your phone lets you access all this internal storage data from any app or from your computer.

You can read more about internal and external storage here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Specifically this quote is very relevant to your question:

> You don’t need any permissions to save files on the internal storage. Your application always has permission to read and write files in its internal storage directory.

Comment: Thank you again Martin I have taken in your reply. About the research; I found that questions similar to my own were immersed in coding fine fine points when for a beginner a basic fundamental answer is best for a good foundation and that is precisely what you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

One line answer :- SQLITE is an integral functionality of android. Your app will WORK even if the mobile device is not rooted.